# System cannot find path specified trying to parse template

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I'm just getting started learning about html/templates in Go. The error I'm getting is that 'system cannot find file path specified'. and the file path is templates/time.html. the location of time.html (the page I'm trying to render) is

src/templates/time.html

the location of my go main is src/timeserver/timerserver.go

here's the code I used

```
func TimeServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
// if user goes to another website after time/...
if req.URL.Path != "/time/" {
    errorHandler(w, req, http.StatusNotFound)
    return
}
cookie, _ := req.Cookie("UUID")
//existCheck := false
//temp2 := ""
profile := Profile{"",time.Now().Format("3:04:04 PM")}
if cookie != nil { // if cookie exist set flags
    name, check := cookieJar.GetValue(cookie.Value)
    profile = Profile{name,time.Now().Format("3:04:04 PM")}
    fmt.Println(name)
    //existCheck = check
    //temp2 = name
    fmt.Println(check)
}
fp := path.Join("templates", "time.html")
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(fp)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

if err := tmpl.Execute(w, profile); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

Comment: From where are you running your application? Paths are relative to that, not the src file.

Comment: i'm running it on a cygwin terminal. I'm going to that page when i go to localhost:8080/time

Comment: Right, but from what folder within your terminal?

Comment: /cygdrive/c/Users/Paul/Documents

gopath = c/Users/Paul/Documents/Home/go

Comment: src is a folder inside c/Users/Paul/Documents/Home/go

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my path wasn't correct. changed

```
fp := path.Join("templates", "time.html")
```

to

```
fp := path.Join("Home/go/src/templates", "time.html")
```